# How to use Pandas groupby to get a count?

Tags: pandas, group-by

I want to group lines by the column value.

This is what the dataframe looks like:

```
Id       model     c3    c4    c5   c6 ...etc
174_ap   c:143     ar    ...
174_dp   c:143     rv    ...
777_ap   c:177     gb    ...
777_dp   c:177     ch    ...
```

There are 2 lines per car, ap is the first check on checkin  and dp the check on checkout. Since the model only repeats on the lines I want to join I tried joining by it with:

```
df = df.groupby('model')
```

But the resulting df looks exactly like the previous one, nothing changed.

What am I doing wrong here?

PS.: The number of columns for each car and check varies.

Comment: You have to then actually *do something* with the grouped df....

Answer (score 0):

It seems only `model` is repeated; so by ***grouping***, if the intend is to get the count, `groupby` does work.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'd split `Id`, set the index with the split and unstack.

```
idx = df.Id.str.split('_', expand=True).values.T.tolist()
df.drop('Id', 1).set_index(idx).stack().unstack([1, 2])

        ap                 dp            
     model  c3  c4  c5  model  c3  c4  c5
174  c:143  ar  ar  ar  c:143  rv  rv  rv
777  c:177  gb  gb  gb  c:177  ch  ch  ch
```